# Passing Success or Failure For Laravel 4 Validation

Tags: php, laravel

I am in the middle of working with my create a user form inside of my restful user controller. While the user is on the form I have it currently posting to the store method. When the form is submitted to the method I want it to validate the user input and then redirect back to the create method for either displaying a success message or an array of error messages if there was a failure in the data validation. Can someone point out what is needed to help me redirect to the create method with either a success message or error message based off the validation test.

```
/**
 * Store a newly created user in storage.
 *
 * @return Response
 */
public function store()
{
    $input = Input::all();

    $validation = Validator::make($input, $rules);

    if ($validation->fails())
    {
        $messages = $validator->all();
    }
    else
    {
        User::create([
            'username' => $input['username'],
            'email_address' => $input['email_address'],
            'password' => $input['password'],
            'role_id' => $input['role']

        ]);
    }

    return Redirect::to('users/create');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use either

```
$messages = $validator->messages();
```

or

```
$failed = $validator->failed();
```

to retrieve error messages. If you want show 'flash' message, you can use 'with' method in redirection.

```
Redirect::to('user/currentroute')->with('message', 'Something wrong');
```

for more details, you should read in [documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/validation)

Comment: Then what is the all() function?

As how would I pass either a success message or failed message not the actual messages.

Comment: do you mean message like 'login is fail' ??? you can pass 'with' method in redirection 

return Redirect::to('user/login')->with('message', 'Login Failed');

Comment: Great, however, what would be the best efficient way to add on the getErrors and getInput because I won't need them if it was a success post.